# Laravel , mysql emoji saved as questionmark

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am implementing emoji support for my forum and I'm facing some issues. 
Emoji is saved as`?` in database, but is shown correctly when i render it in my page.This page use twemoji , so the whole document body is parsed.

Here is my database config:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Here are columns that will contain emojis, so charset is correct. [image: db]

Here is the view:
[image: img]

*In my view , I am using twitter emoji , so emojis are shown correctly.My only concern is that,mysql shows them as `?`*

Comment: Is that how they're stored or is the questionmark just an artefact of where you're trying to display them? If I try to see emoji in the CLI for example I get ? not because they're stored like that but because my CLI can't handle them.

Comment: @apokryfos That may be the problem , i was expecting to see emojis like this : `\u2764\uFE0F`

Comment: Is the database actually UTF8MB4?  you might have configured the connection to use that encoding but if the database isn't in that encoding you could still have problems.  What about the PHP script files, are they all saved as UTF8?  Is the content-type header specifying UTF8 as the character encoding, etc?

Comment: @GordonM in Laravel documentation is said that charset changed from UTF8 to UTF8MB4 to support emojis.So I haven't changed anything to the database

Comment: @tryingtolearn What about your own PHP code?  The code that uses the Laraval libraries?  Is that saved as UTF8?

Answer (score 0):

Check your MySQL tables, they are probably just set to UTF8. In order to support emojis, you should alter them to utf8mb4.

Comment: I have the same problem and my tables and connection is properly set to utf8mb4.